# PHP use else after accessing a if

Tags: php, if-statement

Let's pretend we have a if Statement like:

```
if(something_true) {
    $obj = get(my_obj);
    if($obj !== null) do(something_special);
    else do(the_default); # First else
}
else do(the_default); # Second else
```

Is it possible to exit the if at the first else and instead go on with the second else?

My thought behind this is that i don't have to write the exactly same code two times.

Comment: `if (something_true && get(my_obj) !== null) .. else ..`!?

Comment: This works thanks.
But is there a possibility to kill **only** the if statement after i already accessed it?

Comment: What you want is a `goto`. But `goto`s are bad. Express your logic in terms of simple `if..else` statements, it's always possible one way or another. You just need to learn to structure your thinking accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
if(something_true && get(my_obj) !== null) {
    do(something_special);
}
else do(the_default); # Second else
```

Comment: No i **only** wanted to get the obj if something is true

Comment: post updated. if sonthing_true is true then get(my_obj) checked for null

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Only when the initial condition is false will the second else be executed, that's just simple logic. Just check both something_true and !==null in the first statement and Assuming "the_default" from both esle are the same thing ashkufaraz suggested do it on the second else.

Answer (score 0):

The solution deceze commented works.
If you even need my_obj later on, you can user something like:

```
if(something_true) && (!is_null($obj = get(my_obj);)) {
    do_something_special($obj);
}
else do(the_default); # Second else
```

Technically, ashkufaraz's suggestion solves this problem also, but I wouldn't recommend it because it calls get(my_obj) everytime.

Comment: You are right. But I saw only your original post in which get(my_obj) was called before the condition. The updated post is fine.